# Designing PID controller for 2 servo motor synchronization

Tags: control, transfer-function, servo, pid-controller, root-locus

I am trying to use a PID controller to synchronize wheel speeds in an arduino-bot so that I can get it to drive straight. I am unsure how to approach this problem without knowing the physical properties of the servo motors for the disturbance input (i.e., internal friction, moment of inertia, damping ratio). The ultimate goal of the project is to evaluate the gains of the system using transfer functions and then use MATLAB root locus features to evaluate the response & stability.

Could anyone supply me with some direction on how to get started? I have read some information on using step inputs to evaluate different parameters but do not know how exactly to do this. Tools on hand: arduino due, dc servo's with optical encoders and slotted optical wheel, MATLAB, and Simulink. Also have installed the PID & servo libraries for arduino. Thanks.

Comment: if the wheels are identical diameter, you can use a shaft encoder or if it is brushed sense RPM from current spikes.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the speed of each motor using the encoder input? If not, start with that. Once you have that, you should work out the Kv of the motor. You can either spin it with a drill while monitoring voltage, or you can spin the motor with no load and just observe the speed and applied voltage.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah the encoder wheel has 32 slots so I am just doing the time between slots using attachInterupt command in arduino. So you are saying after finding this, I need to vary voltage and see how speed changes? How would this give me my Kv though?

Comment: In order to estimate Kv you need to know two things simultaneously. Speed and back EMF. Once you know those two things, you can calculate Kv. Ideally, current should be zero or low, because otherwise you will be measuring back emf plus-or-minus series voltage drop.

Comment: @mkeith not to sound dumb, but how would I measure the back emf across a servo? I am very new to this stuff so sometimes even the obvious things are not so to me :-(

Comment: Maybe tell us all about these motors. What are they, where did they come from, how are you planning to control their speed? Are they connected to a servo-drive? Or are you implementing the servo-drive? It is vague, still. I was thinking they were brushed DC motors.

Comment: Parallax 6V continuous servo motors, 8 bit encoders. Attached to the servos are wheels with 32 encoder slots. They are running off an Arduino Due with everything attached to this frame https://www.parallax.com/product/boe-bot-robot. My intent is to measure the time (t) between encoder falling signals then solve for RPM using (2pi/32)*(1/t)*(60/2pi)*(1000) to convert from radians/ms to RPM. I wanted to then implement a PID so i can input RPMs, output (and feedback) PWM, with setpoint @ desired speed. The library in arduino I am using is http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIDLibrary

Comment: Sounds like a brushed DC motor. So your PWM sets the speed? What is the PWM voltage? The effective voltage applied to the motor is VDC * D, where D is the duty cycle, and VDC is the PWM voltage. One thing you could do is set the PWM to 100% and then see how many RPM's you get (with no load on the wheels, so they are free to spin). You could even make a graph of RPM vs duty cycle with no load.

Comment: Yes, the arduino Servo library allows me to adjust speed to the servos based on the width of the pulses. It auto-ranges the inputs from 544-2400 microseconds, 544 being max CW and 2400 being max CCW. My brake torque is achieved at roughly 1500 us for each motor. For instance: right_servo.writeMicroseconds(1500); would hold speed at 0 while right_servo.writeMicroseconds(544) would rotate it at max speed CW.

Comment: By the way, try to avoid all that math inside a micro. Convert human readable units into micro-friendly units outside the micro. Inside the micro, stick to micro-centric units.

Comment: Can you elaborate, are you referring to my speed calculations?

Comment: And I meant ms actually, not us, im using millis() for readings.

Comment: Your PID will run faster if it does not have to perform floating point operations is what I mean.